# Nonlinear optics as gauge theory

Tags: optics, electromagnetism, quantum-optics, non-linear-optics, gauge-theory

the widely used approach to nonlinear optics is a **Taylor expansion** of the dielectric displacement field $\mathbf{D} = \epsilon_0\cdot\mathbf{E} + \mathbf{P}$ in a Fourier representation of the polarization $\mathbf{P}$ in terms of the dielectric susceptibility $\mathcal{X}$:

$\mathbf{P} = \epsilon_0\cdot(\mathcal{X}^{(1)}(\mathbf{E}) + \mathcal{X}^{(2)}(\mathbf{E},\mathbf{E}) + \dots)$ .

This expansion **does not work** anymore if the excitation field has components close to the resonance of the medium. Then, one has to take the whole quantum mechanical situation into account by e.g. describing light/matter interaction by a two-level Hamiltonian.

But this approach is certainly **not the most general one**.

### Intrinsically nonlinear formulations of electrodynamics

So, what kind of nonlinear formulations of electrodynamics given in a Lagrangian formulation are there?

One known ansatz is the **Born-Infeld model** as pointed out by Raskolnikov. There, the Lagrangian density is given by

$\mathcal{L} = b^2\cdot \left[ \sqrt{-\det (g_{\mu \nu})} - \sqrt{-\det(g_{\mu \nu} + F_{\mu \nu}/b)} \right]$

and the theory has some nice features as for example a maximum energy density and its relation to gauge fields in string theory. But as I see it, this model is an intrinsically nonlinear model for the free-space field itself and not usefull for describing nonlinear matter interaction.

The same holds for an ansatz of the form

$\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu} + \lambda\cdot\left( F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu} \right)^2$

proposed by [Mahzoon and Riazi](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10773-006-9242-9?from=SL). Of course, describing the system in **Quantum Electrodynamics** is intrinsically nonlinear and ... to my mind way to complicated for a macroscopical description for nonlinear optics. The **question** is: Can we still get a nice formulation of the theory, say, as a mean field theory via an effective Lagrangian?

I think a suitable ansatz could be

$\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{4}M^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$

where $M$ now accounts for the matter reaction and depends in a nonlinear way on $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$, say

$M^{\mu\nu} = T^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}F_{\alpha\beta}$

where now $T$ is a nonlinear function of the field strength and might obey certain symmetries. The equation $T = T\left( F \right)$ remains unknown and depends on the material.

### Metric vs. $T$ approach

As pointed out by **space_cadet**, one might ask the question why the nonlinearity is not better suited in the metric itself. I think this is a matter of taste. My point is that explicitly changing the metric might imply a non-stationary spacetime in which a [Fourier transformation might not be well defined](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13902/does-a-fourier-transformation-on-a-pseudo-riemannian-manifold-make-sense). It might be totally sufficient to treat spacetime as Lorentzian manifold.
Also, we might need a simple spacetime structure later on to explain the material interaction since the polarization $\mathbf{P}$ depends on the matter response generally in terms of an integration over the past, say

$\mathbf{P}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{t}R\left[\mathbf{E}\right](\tau )d\tau$

with $R$ beeing some nonlinear response function(al) related to $T^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}$.

### Examples for $T$

To illustrate the idea of $T$, here are some examples.
For **free space**, $T$ it is given by $T^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} = g^{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu\beta}$ resulting in the free-space Lagrangian $\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{4}T^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}F_{\alpha\beta}F_{\mu\nu} = -\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$
The Lagrangian of Mahzoon and Riazi can be reconstructed by
$T^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} = \left( 1 + \lambda F^{\gamma\delta}F_{\gamma\delta} \right)\cdot g^{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu\beta}$.
One might be able to derive a Kerr nonlinearity using this Lagrangian.

So, is anyone familiar in a description of nonlinear optics/electrodynamics in terms of a gauge field theory or something similar to the thoughts outlined here?

Thank you in advance.

Sincerely,

Robert

#### Comments on the first Bounty

I want to **thank** everyone actively participating in the discussion, especially **Greg Graviton**, **Marek**, **Raskolnikov**, **space_cadet** and **Willie Wong**. I am enjoying the discussion relating to this question and thankfull for all the nice leads you gave. I decided to give the **bounty** to Willie since he gave the thread a new direction introducing the **material manifold** to us.
For now, I have to reconsider all the ideas and I hope I can come up with a new revision of the question that should be formulated in a clearer way as it is at the moment.
So, thank you again for your contributions and feel welcome to share new insights.

Comment: I am not sure what you want. QED *is* a gauge theory and tells you almost everything you might want to know about interaction of light with matter. But I guess this level of approach is rarely useful. Usually you would want to work with scattering of photons on some lattice and that is just condensed matter physics. To say the least, some of my friends are working in the field of quantum optics and they don't even need to know field theory (not to say gauge theory). Usually they deal just with material science.

Comment: @Marek: thank you for your comment. I edited the question and hope it clearifies what I am asking for. Of course, when working with such a theory, you can almost always forget about its gauge theory character. What I am searching is a gauge theoretical description of nonlinear optics, I am not asking if this would ease any calculations :)

Comment: @Robert: thanks for the clarification but I am still not sure what you want. You just transcribed $\mathbf D$ and $\mathbf H$ in terms of $M$ but this doesn't change physics at all. Are you just looking for a different formalism (in the same spirit as Maxwell equations are better expressed in terms of ${\rm d}{\mathbf F} = {\rm d}^2{\mathbf A} = 0$ and $\delta {\mathbf F} = {\mathbf j}$)?

Comment: @Marek: Thank you again for your well-appreciated comment. Indeed, since the "$M$-formulation is equivalent to Maxwells equations, say $dF=0$ $d*M=*\mathbf{j}$, there is no new physics. So, one part of my question could be: can we identify a symmetry in the matter Lagrangian leading to the known effects of nonlinear optics (Kerr, 2nd harm., ...)? I have to state that I am by no means expert in either nonlinear optics or gauge theory, which is the reason the question might not be posed adequately.

Comment: Look, you are tackling this way too abstractly. Maybe you should start with a specific material with nonlinear optical properties and see how you can describe it. Try to make a gauge-invariant nonlinear field equation for it. If you can't, there's not much point to break your head over it. If you can, you've got a basis to try to generalize. But you'll achieve very little if you can't even model the simplest nonlinear material in this way.

Comment: Just edited out the one French and one German word you used in your text. :) ("ansatz" is sometimes used in English physics tests, but not very often, and many will not understand it.)

Comment: @Noldorin: this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz) will disagree with you. Indeed when reading mathematical and physical literature (both books and papers) I encounter this word far more often than I would like :-) What's the proper English term, by the way?

Comment: @Raskolnikov: Thank you for the suggestion, this seems to be a good starting point.

Comment: @Marek: As the Wikipedia article says, "approach" or "setup" or "starting point" are good approximate English equivalents. I'm sure you are quite aware that Wikipedia articles too often include horribly wrong/unbased statements - hopefully you'll take my observation as a speaker/reader of English. :) Indeed, I don't really see the purpose of using foreign words in papers where there is a perfectly good native equivalent. (In the case of the very rare 'untranslatable', it is fair enough though.)

Comment: Ansatz is fine, one could substitute the word postulate for it, or guess as wikipedia suggests. In his 2D Ising paper, Onsager used "eigenwert" for eigenvalue. Actually, an even better translation would be "proper value". There are a lot of German words that entered science, mainly during the period from the end of the 19th to early 20th century. "Gedankenexperiment" is another one.

Comment: @Noldorin: ah, I missed that it's written there. Anyway, those terms don't quite capture what ansatz is about. @Raskolnikov's guess is a lot closer. But that sounds too random while ansatz is usually a result of a clever insight. I think I remember one of my teachers mentioning something along the lines of an "educated guess".

Comment: @Marek: Yeah, the Wikipedia article suggests that too. ;) I prefer "approach" though. In any case, the word seems to be losing popularity in English, which is only a good one.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: I wouldn't say a lot, far from it. A select few, in fact. There are rather more Latin words present in maths in any case. In any case, as an Englishman I for one do not find it welcome! ("Eigenvalue" is one worth keeping however.)

Comment: @Noldorin: heh, I should probably start reading the references I provide :-) I don't know I am fond of the word. There is no really good alternative in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps there is no *perfect* translation in English. Still, I'm wary of adding more jargon without very good reason. I'm also far too proud of the English language.

Comment: Hey guys, I might notice that this is getting a little off-topic here... yes, I am a German guy and it seems perfectly fine to me to use the english words (with German descent) ansatz, bremsstrahlung, zitterbewegung, eigen* etc. in my posts :) Why shouldn't I? Noldorin, I suppose you use much more words from your mother language in your posts than I do ;)

Comment: Well said Robert. The fact that english is used to communicate physics research, at the **present**. A few hundred years ago it was French and then German. Before that it was Latin. A few hundred years from now it will likely be some combination of Mandarin/Cantonese and Hindi.

Comment: @space_cadet: Indeed. It might not even take that long...

Comment: @robert I was being conservative in my time estimates :-)

Comment: @Robert: Of course you can, just many people may not understand you! I already clarified my point; foreign words are fine, but in my view should only really be used when there is no decent English equivalent. I don't even get your point. I'm English, I so write in English.

Comment: @Noldorin: Thank you for your concern. But I guess that people who are used to scientific literature are familiar with those words. The irony is that the english language is not the mother tongue of a lot of people here; And the first moment a word gets used which is not instantaniously part of the vocabulary of a native speaker, it gets replaced. I really appreciate you helping to clearify things but this one was actually ... quite funny :)

Comment: @Robert: I really don't appreciate the sarcasm. Believe it or not, English is the lingua franca of today, in science and elsewhere. (What a shame the Nazis lost, eh?) And yes, I said that just to fulfill Godwin's law. Thank you.

Comment: @Noldorin: I am sorry if I offended you. I delivered the message with a smile hoping you would see the funny part of the whole discussion. Really, noone doubts your second point but I hope you will excuse yourself later for the part in brackets.

Comment: @Robert: No, it was a joke (and a fact), so not at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just a few random thoughts.

There is something important in your observation that the Born-Infeld model is essentially a free-space model. It is known to Boillat and Plebanski (separately in 1970) that the Born-Infeld model is the only model of electromagnetism (as a connection on a $U(1)$ vector bundle) that satisfies the following conditions

1. Covariance under Lorentz transformations
2. Reduces to Maxwell's equation in the small-field strength limit
3. $U(1)$ gauge symmetry
4. Integrable energy density for a point-charge
5. No birefringence (speed of light independent of polarization).

(the linear Maxwell system fails condition 4.) (See Michael Kiessling, "Electromagnetic field theory without divergence problems", J. Stat. Phys. (2004) doi:10.1023/B:JOSS.0000037250.72634.2a for an exposition on this and related issues.)

Now, since you are interested in nonlinear optics inside a material, instead of in vacuum, I think conditions 1 and 5 can safely be dropped. (Though you may want to keep 5 as a matter of course.) Condition 4 is intuitively pleasing, but maybe not *too* important, at least not until you have some candidate theories in mind that you want to distinguish. Condition 3 you must keep. Condition 2, on the other hand, really depends on what kind of material you have in mind.

In any case, a small suggestion: personally I think it is better to, from the get-go, write your proposed Lagrangian as

$$ L = T^{abcd} F_{ab}F_{cd} $$

instead of $M^{ab}F_{cd}$. I think it is generally preferable to consider Lagrangian field theories of at least quadratic dependence on the field variables. A pure linear term suggests to me an external potential which I don't think should be built into the theory.

If you want something like condition 2, but with a dielectric constant or such, then you must have that $T^{abcd}$ admit a Taylor expansion looking something like

$$ T^{abcd} = \tilde{g}^{ac}\tilde{g}^{bd} + O(|F|) $$

where $\tilde{g}$ is some effective metric for the material. Birefringence, however, you don't have to insert in explicitly: most likely a generic (linear or nonlinear) $T^{abcd}$ you write down will have birefringence; it is only when you try to rule it out that you will bring in some constraints.

An interesting thing is to consider what it means to have an analogous notion to condition 1. In the free-space case, condition 1 implies that the Lagrangian should only be a function of the Lorentz invariant $B^2 - E^2$ (in natural units) and of the pseudo-scalar invariant $B\cdot E$. In terms of the Faraday tensor these two invariants are $F^{ab}F_{ab}$ and $F^{ab}{}^*F_{ab}$ respectively, where ${}^*$ denote the Hodge dual. The determination of the *linear* part of your theory (of electromagnetic waves in a material) is essentially by what you will use to replace condition 1. If you assume your material is isotropic and homogeneous, then some similar sort of scalar + pseudo-scalar invariants is probably a good bet.

Comment: @Willie Wong: Thank you very much for your substantial answer. If I understand your argumentation correctly, one might not be able to find another intrinsically nonlinear formulation that is Lorentz-invariant. Having some relativistic background I would not dare to drop this condition. Do you think having something like $g\times{U(1)}$ with a new group coming from the matter interaction (maybe in some spirit of the electroweak interaction) would be a much better approach? Sincerely

Comment: @Robert: Well, matter interaction will give all sorts of new things, but I do suspect that back-reaction can be in some-sense approximated by pure nonlinearities. One thing to note is the following: you can actually use some sort of Aether-theory idea to break local Lorentz invariance when keeping general covariance for the over-all theory. That is: if you take your optical medium to be some sort of fluid or elastic body evolving (possibly independently of the EM field in the linear approximation except through gravity) in space-time, you can define your "optical metric" $T$ through...

Comment: ...properties of the optical medium. For example, in the linear case, say with a relativistic elastic body as the material, you can construct $\tilde{g}$ from the pull-back of the Riemannian metric on the material manifold, plus a factor coming from the particle world-lines. The overall theory will be generally covariant, but after "fixing" the optical medium you get a local background that breaks Lorentz invariance. So I wouldn't worry too much about breaking Condition 1. Relaxing Conditions 4 and 5 also gives many, many other admissible Lagrangians.

Comment: (I should say that the above is inspired by some recent work of Ted Jacobson's on Einstein-Aether theory, which I think is somewhat related to Horava gravity.)

Comment: @Willie: Thank you very much for your further explanations. I have to admit that the notion of a material manifold is new to me. I always thought of entities defined on a background spacetime but with $\tilde{g}$ as the metric of that manifold, one could basically drop the $T$ approach in favour of this curved material manifold. I suppose the most simple example would be transformation optics with permittivity $\epsilon$ as $\tilde{g}$ if I am not entirely wrong. I am not sure what you mean by particle world lines in this sense; (timelike -> light) geodesics maybe?

Comment: @Robert: Ah! Quick recap of relativistic elasticity. Spacetime $(M,g)$ is $d+1$ dimensional. Material manifold $(N,h)$ is $d$ dimensional Riemann. The material map $\Phi:M\to N$ sort of works like the Eulerian-Lagrangian transformation of fluid dynamics. We assume that $d\Phi$ is on-to and the kernel time-like. The particle word-lines are the curves $\Phi^{-1}(p)$ for some $p\in N$, it denotes, roughly, the trajectory in space-time of a fluid/material particle. For a mathematical introduction see Tahvildar-Zedah "Relativistic and nonrelativistic elastodynamics with small shear strains" ...

Comment: ...[here](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=AIHPA_1998__69_3_275_0). Or http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0393-0440(92)90028-Y of Kijowski and Magli. Bobby Beig's [summary](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0211054) is also very readable. Now, if you just want to implement a non-linear optical medium, you can pretty much forget about the underlying material (just assume that it exists and has some properties) and write $\tilde{g}$ to satisfy what you want. The point is that you *can* justify the breaking of Lorentz symmetry by appealing to this way of thought.

Comment: @Willie: Thank you very much for the explanations and references. I remember roughly that such a manifold is actually only used to justify the ansatz. One defines projections and finds something like $X_\perp = d\phi{(X)} - g(X,\xi)/(g(\xi ,\xi ))\xi$ for $\xi$ timelike and $\tilde{g}(X,Y) \equiv g(X_\perp ,Y_\perp)$ such that all calculations are actually performed on $M$ and everything can be put into $\phi$. This seems to be a sophisticated ansatz, I will also add it to the question if I can formulate it with my own words. My best wishes

Answer (score 7):

Nonlinear is a buzzword used to cover anything that is not linear. Depending on what kind of nonlinearity is involved, and thus what kind of material, there could be one symmetry or another, or there could be no symmetry at all. For instance, in superconductors, gauge symmetry is broken and photons behave as if they have acquired a mass. The result is that magnetic fields have limited penetration in the superconductor. And I think this is still described by linear equations.

I know of one gauge-invariant theory that is non-linear, this model is called the [Born-Infeld model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born%E2%80%93Infeld_model).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was not aware of the Born-Infeld theory of electrodynamics so far but it looks very interesting. You are also pointing to one important thing: different materials will have different symmetries. This is exactly what should cause different materials to obey different kinds of nonlinearities if they can be described by a gauge theory. For the moment we might not focus on further complicated things as symmetry breaking, if this is convenient for you.

Answer (score 4):

You have been asking some seriously interesting questions! Here's my take on this one ...

You say this about the Born-Infeld action:

> But as I see it, this model is an intrinsically nonlinear model for the free-space field itself and not useful for describing nonlinear matter interaction.

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "free-space" field. I take it that you're referring to $ F_{\mu\nu} $. Well there is no reason why one cannot define an $ F_{\mu\nu} $ for waves propagating non-linearly, within a medium or in a vacuum.

The matter-light interaction can be specified (at least in part if not wholly) by the form of $ g_{\mu\nu} $. Now bear with me for a minute. I'm not referring to the metric generated by some kind of matter. The metric in question does not, *a priori*, satisfy the Einstein equations. It is instead the **effective** metric experienced by the light-rays propagating within the given material. See these excellent papers by Ulf Leonhardt and Thomas Philbin [[1]](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0607418),[[2]](http://arxiv.org/abs/0805.4778) for more details on this notion. In brief the off-diagonal components $ g_{ij}$ (where $ (i,j \in \{1,2,3\}\,\, i \neq j) $ encode the susceptibility tensor and the diagonal components $ g_{0i} $ determine the mixing between the electric and magnetic components of the wave.

As for the lagrangian density for the matter-light interaction you posit:

$$ \mathcal{L}_{int} \propto M^{\mu\nu} F_{\mu\nu} = T^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} F_{\alpha\beta} F_{\mu\nu} $$

for flat space (or no-medium) $ T^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} = g^{\mu\nu}g^{\alpha\beta} $, this term reduces to $ F^{\mu\nu} F_{\mu\nu}$ which is nothing more than the Maxwell term ! On the face of it this gives us nothing new, unless we adopt the route outlined above and use the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ to encode the optical properties of the medium.

Another line of thought which exploits this notion of the metric to allow one to speak of an analogy between optical processes and the big-bang is the phenomenal work of Igor Smolyaninov [[3]](http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.2407). This paper was accepted by PRL btw, so its nothing to sneeze at.

Assuming that the above line of reasoning is not fatally flawed, and that one can encode the effects of the medium in the metric, it seems that either the Maxwell or the Born-Infeld action are  perfectly good *candidates* of gauge-invariant actions for your purposes.

```
                                Cheers,
```

---

Edit: **Non-linearity redux**

As @Raskolnikov pointed out, the identification of the components $g_{ab}$ with the optical susceptibilities of a material, does not give us a *nonlinear* material. For that, you have to have a dependence of the susceptibilities on the field strengths themselves. So you have a feedback mechanism $ \mathbf{g} \rightarrow \mathbf{F} \rightarrow \mathbf{g} $ and *therefore* the non-linearity ! Therefore in general, as @robert has been trying to convey to me without success, $\mathbf{g}$ should in general be a function of $\mathbf{F}$.

But then you start treading dangerously close to the speculation that somehow the eventual picture (for the fully non-linear case) might be somehow general relativistic. That is a very tempting idea, but I leave that for another time.

Comment: @space_cadet: Thank you for your nice answer! I am somehow vaguely aware of transformation optics and its ansatz to interprete $\epsilon$ as metric. Of course this is a direction one could try to put the physics into. Nevertheless I don't think that it can work here since <a href="http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13902/does-a-fourier-transformation-on-a-pseudo-riemannian-manifold-make-sense">a Fourier transformation will only make sence if one has a timelike killing field</a>. That was the reason I tried to put it into "T".

Comment: Ah, nice thing to point out you can model nonlinearities with an effective metric! This reminds me of a lecture I had on [Finsler manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finsler_manifold). If I remember correctly they are used in a similar way with main applications in geophysics for propagation of all kinds of seismic waves (where one has also longitudinal waves; this is perhaps what you mean by $g_{\mu\nu} not necessarily satisfying EFE, which do require transversal waves). I wonder whether that formalism can also be adapted for the Robert's case.

Comment: @Robert - timelike k.v.f ... ?? You're making it too complicated. You have a default timelike k.v.f. The medium that the light propagates through presumably sits in some background geometry which is close to being flat unless your lab is in orbit around a *really* massive object. The t.v.k.f in in this case is the usual clock-time. In looking at these problems it is tempting to get caught up in the jargon. One should avoid such habits if possible.

Comment: @Marek - i should mention the caveat that I do not know how (or if) this approach can work for dispersive media - which constitute a large fraction of non-linear materials. However, it works just fine for optically anisotropic materials and those with [magnetoelectric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiferroics#Magnetoelectric_effect) properties.

Comment: @space_cadet: Thank you for your comment, you are absolutely right, one should not make things more complicated than they are. I just thought that one should not touch the metric since in difference to transformation optics, one will need the time dependence of the field for the material response (e.g. in terms of a convolution). Changing the metric (by means of the material) might imply that a Fourier transformation is not feasible anymore. From this argumentation, can you understand that I would like to grasp the dynamics in T even though a description in g might also work?

Comment: what do you mean by 'T' and 'dynamics in T'?

Comment: I also admit that the problem statement might not be very clear which makes it difficult to get the idea. I am sorry that for now I cannot formulate it better.

Comment: @Robert, just a note: you lose Fourier transformation as soon as you allow non-linear effects. It's not a big secret that non-linear PDE are genuinely hard and only very few of them have been solved (by methods such as Lax pair and Inverse scattering). So I am now quite confused as to which sense of *non-linear* are you pertaining...

Comment: @space_cadet: With T I mean the tensor T that depends on the field strength F. I called this dependence dynamics since if it is nonlinear, solutions to $L = <M,F> = T(F,F)$ will not only be stationary, if this is a convenient nomenclature.

Comment: T depends on F? How so? Isn't T just given by $ T^{abcd} = g^{ab} g^{cd} $ ? No $F^{ab}$ in that expression

Comment: @Marek: Thank you for your thought. It is perfectly true that nonlinear PDE's cannot be (generally) transformed to algebraic equations by means of a Fourier/Laplace transformation. But I think we would need it anyways since $D = \epsilon_0 \mathbf{E} + \mathbf{P}$ where now $P(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{t} Y(\mathbf{E})(\tau)d\tau$ with $Y$ beeing some nonlinear function, related to the tensor $T$.

Comment: @space-cadet, that would only give a "linear material".

Comment: @space_cadet: This T that I explicitely gave in the question is just an example of how it would look like for the interaction with free space. Then we just have $T(F,F) = F\wedge \star F$ and we reconstruct the ordinary free-space lagrangian. If now $T$ depends on $F$ itself, the theory is intrinsically nonlinear. I hope my way of explaining is not too confusing.

Comment: @robert, i sort of follow you, but i don't know where you're going with this.

Comment: @raskolnikov - that is what i was afraid of. i mentioned as much in an earlier comment. i was hoping no one would look that closely ;-) there goes my bounty :(

Comment: @space_cadet: I can see your point, I think it is a problem that the formulation of the question is not very clear. I will have to think about how to motivate the notation maybe by calculating an example as Raskolnikov was suggesting. I might be able for example to derive the Kerr effect with $T^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} = \left( 1 + \lambda F^{\gamma\delta}F_{\gamma\delta} \right)\cdot g^{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu\beta}$.

Comment: @robert. See my edit. You, my friend, are onto something !

Comment: @space_cadet: Thanks for the further edit. I want to try to convey you from another perspective :) The field $F$ in the Standard model is intrinsically nonlinear by the non-Abelian character of the underlying group. Indeed, it can be interpreted as a curvature. But not as a curvature of spacetime, it is a curvature of the fibre-bundle. Spacetime is in this theory not changed at all, it is just a background Minkowski one and I surely see no reason to bend spacetime via nonlinear optical effects. Then, we have GR as you mentioned and everything is getting messi (FT not defined etc).

Comment: @space_cadet: Just to add: Not I am, we are :) I asked some time ago if a community page can write a paper. If there is something in this question, it might be worth the try.

Comment: @space_cadet: Now with the explanations given by Willie I can finally see your point of using a rescaled metric $\tilde{g}$. Lets say we both were right but talking from a slightly different perspective ;) I will incorporate the idea into the question if I can put it in my own words. Greetings

Answer (score 4):

In a condensed matter field theory course, I learned the following: *microscopically*, the Lagrangian for the electromagnetic field looks like it is supposed to, coupling minimally to the particle coordinates.

$$ L = \sum_i\left( \frac m2 (p_i-\frac ec \mathbf A(r_i))^2 - e\Phi(r_i) + \dots \right) .$$

On a *macroscopic* level, however, after getting rid of all the individual particle degrees of freedom via the grand canonical ensemble, new behavior may emerge. Namely, the *effective Lagrangian* for the electromagnetic field in the body may look very different from a linear one. For example, the effective action for the e.m. field in a superconductor is

$$ S_{\text{eff}}[\mathbf A] = \frac\beta2 \int d^3r \mathbf A^\perp(r) \left(-\frac 1{\mu_0}\nabla^2 + \frac {n_s}m \right)\mathbf A^\perp(r)$$

where $\mu_0$ is the vacuum permeability, $n_s$ the superfluid density, $m$ the electron mass and $\mathbf A^\perp$ is the perpendicular component of the gauge field, defined in Fourier space as $\mathbf A^\perp(q) = \mathbf A(q) - q(q\cdot \mathbf A(q))/q^2$. The difference to the vacuum action is the additional "mass term" $n_s/m$, which causes the Meissner effect.

I suppose that you are asking for the most general form that such effective actions may have? I don't have an answer, but I don't see why a most general form should actually exist in the first place.

Comment: Hi @greg, that is not what the question is asking. Their is no requirement for the non-linear theory in question to be an effective theory. Also there are "general forms" for effective actions. Many different microscopic model hamiltonians could yield the same effective theory macroscopically - as long as the hamiltonians share the same symmetries. This property is known as universality. Also any action, effective or not, has to satisfy the basic requirements for gauge invariance (or invariance under canonical transformations). This limits the possible form of the action very effectively.

Comment: @Greg Graviton: Thank you for your answer. May I ask you if there exists a script ot your course on the internet? I think getting my hands on the derivation of this macroscopical effective action, I may give the question a new direction.

Comment: @space_cadet: I think the answer is just fine. The problem is that my question is not very specific and just relies on a vague idea. I will actually have to spend more time on it which is atm unfortunately not so easy :)

Comment: @space_cadet: I thought that Robert was asking about nonlinear optics in matter. The most general form is of course $L = f(\mathbf A,\Phi)$ with some arbitrary $f$ that is gauge invariant, but that's kinda pointless. But as you note, a more specialized classification of common effective theories according to the microscopic Hamiltionians and their symmetries would be a very good answer. Unfortunately, I'm not knowledgeable about that.

Comment: @Robert: I'm afraid, there is no script available. However, the course followed the book by [Altland, Simons](http://books.google.com/books?id=EYbIQQAACAAJ) very closely. The effective action I'm talking about is given in equation (6.39), chapter 6.4. Maybe you can download an electronic version from your university library or somewhere else. Be warned that I wouldn't have been able to understand (even a bit of) the book alone, having a course was necessary for me.

Comment: @Greg: Thank you for the explicit reference. I will see if I can follow its lines :)