# How to plot Joukowski airfoil?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, aerodynamics, software, aircraft

We have an asymmetric potential flow past the cylinder (i.e. 2D circle) of radius $R$ of well-known complex velocity $W$:

$$
\tilde{W} = v_\infty e^{-i\alpha} + i\frac{\Gamma}{2\pi(\zeta - \mu)} - \frac{v_\infty R^2 e^{i\alpha}}{(\zeta - \mu)^2}
$$

where $\mu = \mu_x + i\mu_y$ is the complex coordinate of cylinder axis (circle center) and the rest is just as usual (e.g. [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joukowsky_transform#Velocity_field_and_circulation_for_the_Joukowsky_airfoil)). Circulation $\Gamma$ satisfies the Kutta condition.

**How do I calculate parameters of the airfoil and streamlines?**

The transformed velocity should be:

$$
W = \frac{\tilde{W}}{\frac{dz}{d\zeta}} = \frac{\tilde{W}}{1-\frac{\ell}{\zeta^2}}.
$$

And the airfoil? How do I properly transform the circle defined in a plane corresponding to $\tilde{W}$?

Comment: I appreciate that the links below are basic stuff and well known to you, this is just for future related questions from other people: http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/K-12/airplane/map.html and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4847/how-is-the-joukowsky-transform-used-to-calculate-the-flow-of-an-airfoil?rq=1

Comment: Integrate the velocity field to the complex potential $\Omega(z)$. Then $\mathrm{Re}(\Omega = const$ are the equipotentials, amongst which the aerofoil itself and $\mathrm{Im}(\Omega)=const$ are the streamlines. [My answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/77735/26076) works this problem out in detail.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Python code for generating the streamlines of the flow past a Joukowski airfoil (static plot and animated streamlines, asociated to a rotating airfoil):

http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/empet/Math/blob/master/Joukowski-airfoil.ipynb
http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/empet/Math/blob/master/Joukowski-airfoil-rotation-online.ipynb