# Can Quantum Stealth be Real?

Tags: visible-light

I've recently heard about this new material called Quantum Stealth which is suppost to be a replicate of Harry Potter's 'Invisibilty cloak' . Apparently the material, bends light waves around a target which allows complete invisibility. Is all this true?

Comment: I do seem to recall reading about something like this quite a while back, but I believe the functionality was limited to very small objects in the microwave part of the EM spectrum.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48240/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

In the recent development of [Metamaterials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamaterial) allows some configuration when invisibility of an objects can be achieved for certain range of wavelengths. The initial development focused for microwave and infrared ranges. There are results for [visible range](http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v106/i6/e067402) as well. So we are in a very early stage but it is very unlikely that on can achieve invisibility effect for broad range of wavelengths.